# Efficiently convert dataframe rows to numpy arrays

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, numpy, pyodbc

I am using `pyodbc` to perform queries to a large SQL Server database. Because SQL can not hold native `numpy` arrays, data is stored in regular strings representative of `numpy` arrays. When I load this data to a `DataFrame`, it is as follows:

```
Id       Array1                             Array2
1        -21.722315 11.017685 -23.340452    2754.642 481.94247 21.728323
...
149001   1.611342 1.526262 -35.415166       6252.124 61.51516 852.15167
```

However, I then want to perform operations on `Array1` and `Array2`, so I need to convert them to actual `numpy` arrays. My current way of doing this is applying `np.fromstring` to the entire dataset column.

```
df['Array1'] = df['Array1'].apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x, dtype=np.float32, sep = ' '))
df['Array2'] = df['Array2'].apply(lambda x: np.fromstring(x, dtype=np.float32, sep = ' '))
# Elapsed Time: 9.524s
```

*Result:*

```
Id       Array1                               Array2
1        [-21.722315, 11.017685, -23.340452]  [2754.642, 481.94247, 21.728323]
...
149001   [1.611342, 1.526262, -35.415166]     [6252.124, 61.51516, 852.15167]
```

While this code works, I don't believe it is efficient nor scalable. Are there more computationally efficient ways of transforming a large amount of data in `numpy` arrays?

Comment: have you checked if this can be done on the server side during the call to the database? I believe PostgreSql handles arrays for instance. just in case...

Comment: You could store the data as a byte array in a varbinary column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`tobytes()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tobytes.html) to get the underlying bytestring and [`frombuffer()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) to convert back will be much more efficient. One detail is that the array dimensions are lost after `tobytes()`, so you may need to resize the after `frombuffer()`.

Comment: Just had to specify `dtype=np.float32` and all worked perfectly. 16x performance increase with this method.